# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type In DatabaseReferance

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building a simple chat application. In user fragment, if we click on user it get crashed and go to previous activity if there is previous chat. While there is no chat with that user fragment works fine, but when we type message and click send message store on Firebase and app crashes, similarly if there is chat, chat fragment get crashed.

I think problem is in `mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener())` method. Code and error is given below. I saw other answers but didn't understand with my code.

MessageActivity.java

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView username;

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

    ImageView btn_send;
    EditText send_msg;

    Intent mIntent;
    MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    List<Chat> mChats;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        btn_send = findViewById(R.id.img_btn_send);
        send_msg = findViewById(R.id.text_send);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        mIntent = getIntent();

        final String userid = mIntent.getStringExtra("userid");

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = send_msg.getText().toString();
                if (!msg.equals("")){
                    sendMessage(mFirebaseUser.getUid(), userid, msg);
                }
                send_msg.setText("");
            }
        });

        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                assert user != null;
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                if ( user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
                }else {
                    Glide.with(MessageActivity.this).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }

                readMessage(mFirebaseUser.getUid(), userid, user.getImageURL());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message){
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("sender", sender);
        hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
        hashMap.put("message", message);

        mDatabaseReference.child("Chats").setValue(hashMap);
    }

    private void readMessage(final String myId, final String userID, final String imageURL){
        mChats = new ArrayList<>();

        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mChats.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Chat chat = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Chat.class);

                    assert chat != null;
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myId) && chat.getSender().equals(userID) || chat.getReceiver().equals(userID) && chat.getSender().equals(myId)){
                        mChats.add(chat);
                    }

                    mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChats, imageURL);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ChatsFragment.java

```
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;

    FirebaseUser fUser;
    DatabaseReference mReference;

    private List<String> userList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        userList = new ArrayList<>();

        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                    if (chat.getSender().equals(fUser.getUid())){
                        userList.add(chat.getReceiver());
                    }
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fUser.getUid())){
                        userList.add(chat.getSender());
                    }
                }

                readChats();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void readChats() {

        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    for (String id : userList){
                        if (user.getId().equals(id)){
                            if (mUsers.size() != 0){
                                for ( User user1 : mUsers){
                                    if ( !user.getId().equals(user1.getId()));
                                    mUsers.add(user);
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                mUsers.add(user);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Error is :

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:423)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:212)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a smaller code sample to reproduce the problem? Just try removing some irrelevant details, so that others don't get confused by the amount of code. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: is this okay? or make it more smaller?